# A poetic riddle with the answer sophisticated

Tags: poetry, poetic

I'm working on a gift for my best friend who is leaving the town soon. She loves poetry but I suck at it (big time).

And my gift is something similar to the concept of Dash & Lily's book of Dares. Her favorite adjective is **sophisticated**.

Can anyone help me with a poetic riddle for that? The answer should be sophisticated and it should mention, in a way, that it's her favorite adjective.

I know it's not a forum for these types of requests but I need to get this done and I will appreciate you guys taking your time for doing this. A pretty please with a cherry on top. :)

Comment: provide some context, what's the style?

Comment: How much money are you willing to spend for this commissioned work of art?

Comment: This is the [*shadiest topic*](http://wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=Sophisticated&t=1000&a=n) I've seen here in a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get this done, time is pressing, how about:

*Goodbye! I must say*

*I do prefer you stay*

*I have a riddle for you*

*Which is a favorite word too*:

*It has wisdom in the first sound*

*In the last, a woman can be found.*

so·phis·ti·cat·ed/səˈfistəˌkādəd/

The first sound 'səˈfistə' has 'sophy', a Greek word for wisdom.The last sound 
'kādəd' has Kay, a woman name.

You are a native speaker, you can tweak it to a proper English poem, [poetic license](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/1362834/poetic-license) permitting.Also you can use different words playing on different aspects of 'so·phis·ti·cat·ed/səˈfistəˌkādəd'.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot for this help. I accidentally sent it to her, instead of a different friend because I was too sleepy.. haha. Anyways, I will take care of it. THANKS A LOT!!! :)